# stupid Syntax Error with conditionals?

Tags: python, python-2.7

OK, i have code like this:

```
def main():
    while something == True:
        dosomething()
main()
```

but in another part of the code i do the same and i don't get any error
if i change `while` for `if` the error change instead of say

```
while something == True:
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

the interpreter say:

```
 if something == True:
                     ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

so, its the same but i get different errors

what´s happens? 
is python kidding me?
PD: change `def main()` to `def main():`

Comment: End your function signature with a ":".

Comment: @SyedMauzeRehan thanks for answered but this is a mistake when I write this int SOF but the error persist

Comment: Is `something` a variable in your code or are you using it as a stand-in for a more complicated comparison (which may have a syntax error)?

Comment: `SyntaxError` exceptions are often reported on the line following the location of the actual error. Check the previous line to make sure you're not missing a closing parenthesis or bracket.

Comment: @tdelaney is a stand-in for simplify the code but it as same as my code

Comment: There are two types of people in this world: Those that show a few lines of code to figure out a syntax error, and those who don't get their question answered.

Comment: @Blckknght thanks, i know that and i think this is useful but if the ^ say the error is in the while exactly in "e"(i suppose) but the word while isn't bad write

Comment: ohh @tdelaney i was in the two types of people im so happy¡¡ but i think you forgot people who receive negative votes and nobody can resolve the question

Comment: I think that @tdelaney's point was that you need to show at least a few lines of code on either side of this error before anyone can see what's going on. The single line that you have posted isn't enough; the problem is almost certainly related to how that line exists in the context that we can't see.

Comment: thanks @bgporter im bad on use of English and i cant catch the irony. the problem was in the last line so i forget a ) and this is why the interpreter say the problem is in the ´e´ on while

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a `:` at the end of your `def main()` line (should be `def main():`).

Comment: Yup. Python is not "kidding" you.

Comment: @MaxNoel thanks but the error persist and if the error was : in the function the interpreter return:   
def main()
          ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Answer (score 0):

I think your if and while block is missing a statement, try

```
while something == True:
    pass
```

Comment: No that would raise a different error (expected an indented block bla bla)